# input element 's height is not correct

Tags: css

I write these code and check it in chrome console that as shown in Figure. two extra two pixel.

```
<input type="text" id="keyWords" class="search-ipt" placeholder="请输入订单号/借款人姓名">

.search-ipt {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

[input's attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10sgQ.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide html also?

Comment: have you reset your browser default values to the elements  as zero?

Answer (score 2):

`input` inherits browsers default `padding` value (inspect the element and you can see all the styles that the element inherits). So, you have to add some value (or set it to 0) to that property to override the browsers:

```
.search-input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0; /* or some other value */
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcpj3c52/)

Use some CSS reset in the future, like [Mayer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), which *"resets"* all the default browsers values.

Comment: Yes, the element inherits all the browser default styles if you don't specify them - just like `padding` here.

Answer (score 0):

its Perfect from my side

```css
.search-ipt {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 150px;
    border:none  ;
    outline: none;
    padding:0;
  background:#ccc;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keyWords" class="search-ipt" placeholder="请输入订单号/借款人姓名">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `.search-ipt` `padding:0` and check you will get `150x28`.

```
.search-ipt {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding:0;/*Add this*/
}
```